# Windows Phone/Kinect style tilt effect for WPF

Tags: wpf

Anyone know how to go about achieving the tilt effect you see on Windows Phone 7 tiles or on the tiles in the Kinect UI on XBOX in WPF?

**Sample screenshot:**

[image]

There are a number of libraries that do it for Silverlight but all rely on the PlaneProjection which isn't in WPF.

Here is a link that shows what I mean and how to do it in Silverlight. http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/05/metro-in-motion-part-4-tilt-effect/?utm_source=Silverlight-Zone.com&utm_medium=SilverlightZone&utm_campaign=kunal2383

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post picture or video showing that effect?

Comment: You can see here an example of what I mean, and how it's implemented in Silverlight.   http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/05/metro-in-motion-part-4-tilt-effect/?utm_source=Silverlight-Zone.com&utm_medium=SilverlightZone&utm_campaign=kunal2383

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I created my own Tilt effect behavior for WPF, take a look to [my post](https://mareinsula.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/wpf-tilt-effect-behavior/) and tell me what you think.

I have updated it with KeepDraging Property and TiltFactor Property and the possibility to add it directly to the panel. I hope you enjoy it now

Comment: Thats great Mareinsula!  Not sure if you are aware but there is one minor issue where if you hold your mouse down and drag off the animated item the item remains tilted until you let go of the mouse.  It should release as soon as you mouse off the item but anyway that is a really great starting point.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The tilt effect on WP7 relies on [PlaneProjection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.planeprojection%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which is exclusive to Silverlight.

There are several projects out there that have attempted to [port PlaneProject to WPF](http://blog.endquote.com/post/710116433/planeprojection-in-wpf) but the tilt effect itself has not been ported yet.