# Windows Phone button style for desktop WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, styling

I'm trying to achieve the same button style of the WP even with the little conditional tilt when pressed. It is possible to do that with WPF?

[image: What I want]

Here is what I have, doing a Ctrl+C Ctrl+V of the button style directly from the xaml SDK's. Using the White theme.

[image]

There is no tilt when pressed and the text is a not center aligned.

EDIT: Changed "flip" to "tilt".

Comment: I've never had a chance to touch on a Windows Phone as well as never programmed Windows Phone, so I don't know about the effect here. It would be better if you post some link to some GIF or video showing the effect.

Comment: I think flip effect is called 'Tilt' effect in Windows Phone. You can take a look how it was implemented earlier by some gut. The [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634201/windows-phone-kinect-style-tilt-effect-for-wpf).